# Datatable - JSON not being shown of size larger than 4KB

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, datatable

I am using data table to display data returned by a SQL Server 2008 procedure called in Codeigniter via Ajax($POST). Initially I made a very simple procedure with no input parameters, it only returns a list of JSON objects. 
Below are my questions and my Codeigniter function returning JSON, AJAX function and JSON structure returned by my Codeigniter function:

1) JSON not returned for chunk larger than 4KB, it simply converts to HTML:

[image: High lighted data not shown as JSON]

2) What if one of my procedure returns lets say 5000+ record and i want to display it in data table, is my way of doing it right? Or i should use some other best practices:

**Codeigniter Function:**

```
public function executeProc()
 {
    $sqlsrvr = $this->load->database('test', true);

    // Get the input values of the procedure

    $arr = array();
    parse_str($_POST['str'],$arr); 

    //get Procedure Name
    $procName = $_POST['procName'];

    $sp ='exec secondProc';
    $query = $sqlsrvr->query($sp);//->result();
    $jawad =  $query->result_array();

    $this->output->set_header('Content-type: application/json');  
     echo json_encode($jawad);

 }
```

**AJAX Function**

```
$(document).on('click','#executeProc',function(e){

$('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');
  e.preventDefault();

  var jawad = $( ".jawad" ).serialize();

 $.post('<?=base_url();?>command/executeProc',
    {str:jawad,procName:$('#procName').val()},

   function(html){
    //loading data table on return
    $('#example').dataTable( {
     "data": html,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "AppointmentID" },
        { "data": "FirstName" },
        { "data": "LastName" },
        { "data": "AppointmentDate" }
    ]
  } );

    });

});
```

**JSON Sample:**

```
[
    {
        "AppointmentID": "1",
        "FirstName": "Test",
        "LastName": "test",
        "AppointmentDate": "2013-01-12"
    },
    {
        "AppointmentID": "2",
        "FirstName": "dfg",
        "LastName": "dfg",
        "AppointmentDate": "2013-01-01"
    }
]
```

-----AFTER EDIT------
**STRANGE BEHAVIOR(JSON tab converts to HTML for larger records)**

FOR 40 records that get displayed on data table
[image]

FOR records larger then 40 that don't get displayed on data table
[image]

Comment: 1) post your working json data (40 records) and not working response (45 records). I believe that the first record of  'AppointmentID' is seems to be wrong value (may be null or something) 2) you need to look serverside datatable which is taking data from server for each page click

Comment: In the HTML section my records that get displayed, imn Javescript section which throw a error http://jsfiddle.net/k3hmrpL4/

Comment: Please also see for records larger than 40 JSON tab in firefox disappears.

Comment: can you try html = json.parse(html); before giving to datatable. but still you need to investigate this in your php code that why are you getting HTML response instead of JSON

Comment: i get this error:ReferenceError: json is not defined

Comment: Sorry json should be caps... html = JSON.parse(html);